# How to calculate column width considering wrapText and merge columns if there?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am little bit new to Apache POI and I want to calculate column width dynamically on basis of Font Size, Family and also have to consider if wrap text, merge cells are used.

Here is by below code that I am using:

```
XSSFCellStyle xs = (XSSFCellStyle) cell.getCellStyle();
             XSSFFont xf = xs.getFont();
             AttributedString attributedString = new AttributedString(value );
              attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FAMILY, xf.getFontName(), 0,  value.length());
              attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE, (float)xf.getFontHeightInPoints());
              if (xf.getBold()) attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.WEIGHT, TextAttribute.WEIGHT_BOLD,  0, value);
              if (xf.getItalic()) attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.POSTURE, TextAttribute.POSTURE_OBLIQUE,  0, value);

              FontRenderContext fontRenderContext = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);

              TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(attributedString.getIterator(), fontRenderContext);
              Rectangle2D bounds = layout.getBounds();
              double frameWidth = bounds.getX() + bounds.getWidth();
             
              int defaultCharWidth = 11;
              this.sheet.setColumnWidth(cell.getColumnIndex(), (int)Math.round(frameWidth / defaultCharWidth * 256));
```

But this is not working as accepted
what I am getting is something like this:
[image]

and what is expected output is:

[image]

I am not sure how to calculate it properly or what mistake I am doing? Please Help

Comment: Why is the calculation needed? Why not simply using [Sheet.autoSizeColumn](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#autoSizeColumn-int-boolean-)? For ex.: `this.sheet.autoSizeColumn(cell.getColumnIndex(), true);`. This internally calculates the needed column width.

Comment: I need calculation as I have one specific view which need to be maintained same in all formats like html, pdf and excel also so need to count the width accordingly. In other formats it is working but in excel it is not giving proper view.

Comment: `Apache poi` uses [SheetUtil](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.0/org/apache/poi/ss/util/SheetUtil.html) to calculate column width. This provides `getCellWidth` and `getColumnWidth`. Or have a look at the [sources](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_0_0/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/util/SheetUtil.java?view=markup) to get how this gets calculated.

Comment: tried all but not getting as expected result and my calculation also is similar to it.